# How to Aggregate All Values in a Worksheet for a Particular Unique ID (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets

Assume that you have a worksheet that contains two columns: unique_id and variable_a. Assume further that there are multiple values in the worksheet for each unique_id (i.e. multiple rows that start with the same unique_id). Now, my task is to aggregate all of these values by unique_id. Per the recommendation in the comments, I use SUMIF(Sheet1!$A:$A,A2,Sheet1!$D:$D) to pull all of these values. However, some of the cells for variable_a are #N/A. Obviously, this returns a #NA for the SUMIF function as well. How can I edit the SUMIF function so that it does not include these #N/A values since I do not want to filter out and delete all rows containing #NA values in the original spreadsheet?

**Sample Worksheet**

[image: Example of worksheet]

**Output Worksheet**

[image: Example of required output worksheet]

Comment: By *'your task'* do you mean **my task**? By *'you would have to ...'* do you mean **I would have to ...**

Comment: look at the SUMIF function

Comment: @charles-williams Thank you for the kind reply! You are correct. I had tried SUMIF but I had set the second criteria to "=A2" in parentheses. After reading your note, I went back and read the documentation on SUMIF. And, I replaced "=A2" with A2. And, it worked. SUMIF(Sheet1!$A:$A,A2,Sheet1!$D:$D) solved the problem. No vlookup necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IF function and use Vlookup as a part of it... post the example requirement, I will share you the answer...

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have edited the question as requested.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0tqy.png)

You can get from below one